# Calculating Yearly Income in Python

Tags: python

Right now, I wanted to make simple calculations of how much profit would a web design company make in year following the below criteria:

1. The company sells themes, plugins and designs.
2. each theme costs 20, plugin costs 10 and design costs 50
3. the company steadily maintains total sales of 5 themes, 4 plugins and 2 designs each week (Fixed amount)
4. Recently, the company managed to sell an extra item of each through each week like the following >>

In week 1, they sell 5 themes, 4 plugins and 2 designs (the default)

In week 2, they sell 6 themes, 5 plugins and 3 designs

In week 3, they sell 7 themes, 6 plugins and 4 designs
etc..

Here is the code that I managed to create ( I wanted to see how much would the company would make each week based on the above sequence)

```
design_sales = 2
theme_sales = 5
plugin_sales = 4
design_price = 50
theme_price = 20
plugin_price = 10
design_profit = design_sales * design_price
theme_profit = theme_sales * theme_price
plugin_profit = plugin_sales * plugin_price
firstWeekSales = design_profit + theme_profit + plugin_profit
WeeklyIncrease = firstWeekSales - (theme_price + plugin_price + design_price)
for week in range(1,53):
    WeeklyIncrease = WeeklyIncrease + theme_price + plugin_price + design_price
    print('Week %s = %s' % (week, WeeklyIncrease))
```

How can I calculate the overall year profit after I do this?

Comment: Note that you can't calculate  profit from this information - you have no measure of costs.  However, I assume your question is about the programming not the accounting.

Comment: The math for WeeklyIncrease subtracts price of one unit from price of multiple units.  Then the for loop adds price rather than price * quantity.  I think you should reformulate the question after the math is right.  Perhaps you should use the definition "sales = price * quantity" and avoid the word "profit".  Is "weekly increase" equal to the current week sales, or is it equal to the total sales year-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to organize your data into a dictionary or list.  Here is an example using lists:

```
# list of tuples (themes, plugins, designs) with week-1 as the index
weekly_sales_quantity = [
    (5, 4, 2),
    (6, 5, 2),
]
```

The next step is to initialize, iterate, and sum year-to-date (ytd):

```
theme_price = 20
plugin_price = 10
design_price = 50
theme_sales_ytd = 0
plugin_sales_ytd = 0
design_sales_ytd = 0
for week in weekly_sales_quantity:
    theme_quantity, plugin_quantity, design_quantity = week
    theme_sales = theme_quantity * theme_price
    plugin_sales = theme_quantity * theme_price
    design_sales = theme_quantity * theme_price
    theme_sales_ytd += theme_sales
    plugin_sales_ytd += plugin_sales
    design_sales_ytd += design_sales
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there are 4 weeks in a month. On the fourth week, they sell 5 themes, 4 plugins and 2 designs (the default).

Here's the code.

```
design_sales = 2
theme_sales = 5
plugin_sales = 4
design_price = 50
theme_price = 20
plugin_price = 10
yearly_profit = 0

for month in range(0,12):
    for week in range(0,3):
        # calculate weekly profit for each product
        design_profit = design_sales * design_price
        theme_profit = theme_sales * theme_price
        plugin_profit = plugin_sales * plugin_price
        # add weekly profit to yearly profit
        yearly_profit += (design_profit + theme_profit + plugin_profit)
        # accumulate extra sale
        design_sales += 1 
        theme_sales += 1
        plugin_sales += 1
    # fourth week
    design_sales = 2
    theme_sales = 5
    plugin_sales = 4
    # profit for fourth week
    design_profit = design_sales * design_price
    theme_profit = theme_sales * theme_price
    plugin_profit = plugin_sales * plugin_price
    # add fourth week profit to yearly profit
    yearly_profit += (design_profit + theme_profit + plugin_profit)

print(yearly_profit)
```